# How to read new line separated integers efficiently in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io, int

I need to read a large list of integers from a file but as efficiently as possible in terms of  time. Integers are newline separated. I guess reading one integer at a time using cin would cause very frequent reads.

I guess reading a number of integers in one go will speed it up! But how to do this?

Edit: I used the file that is redirected to stdin. So I was reading the integers using cin.

Comment: define efficiently. You can't read a more than one at time (as the input is serial (the stream is inherently not parallel). The standard input is already buffered so it read huge chunks into memory than reads each integer from  the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code using the stl

```
std::ifstream myFile("TheNameOfYourFile");
std::list<int> myList;

int number;
while (myFile >> number)
{
    myList.push_back(number);
}
```

Comment: This would again read the numbers one by one. May be using buffer is a good idea as Griwes suggested!

Comment: @Zongo: it's not STL, it's C++ Standard Library. Monish: well, this method also buffers file, as hardware cannot read less than a physical sector (512 bytes on 1.44MiB floppy, AFAIR 2048 bytes on CD/DVD and hard drive). So it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Don't test the state of the file as the the were condition (AS EOF is not set until you read past it). Test the result of the read operation as a fail to read (because of EOF) will result in the loop not being entered. Your method would result in an extra random value being inserted onto the end of the list.

Comment: @Griwes - he could be talking about the std::list?

Answer (score 2):

From hardware point of view, you cannot just read few bytes - you read entire sector into memory and next sectors are buffered while you read them using `fstream` (I guess you was thinking about `fstream` when wrote `cin`...).

You can, however, do it as Boost::Spirit examples do - IDK if it's faster in terms of buffering; probably it's just as fast as normal reading, due to hardware point of view I explained. It would need some tweaking to get file's contents into `stringstream` instead of `string`, though.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/example/lex/example.hpp

Answer (score 1):

If you need the best performance:

1. Parsing integers from ASCII strings is slower than reading binary data.
2. `iostream` IO is much slower than `stdio.h` IO.

To read `nitems` integers from a binary file/stdin into an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  // first read number of integers in the array
  size_t nitems = -1;
  if (fread(&nitems, sizeof(nitems), 1, stdin) != 1) {
    perror("nitems");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // allocate memory for the array
  int *arr = (int*) malloc(nitems*sizeof(*arr));
  if (arr == NULL) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // read integers
  size_t n = fread(arr, sizeof(*arr), nitems, stdin);
  if (n != nitems) {
    perror("fread");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // do something with `arr` here
  for (int* a = arr; a != &arr[nitems]; ++a)
    printf("%d\n", *a);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

To convert line-separated integers to the efficient binary format:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  using namespace std;

  // read integers from ascii file/stdin
  int i = -1;
  vector<int> v;
  while (cin >> i) v.push_back(i);
  if (v.size() == 0) return 2;

  // write the array in binary format
  size_t nmemb = v.size();
  if (fwrite(&nmemb, sizeof(nmemb), 1, stdout) != 1 || 
      fwrite(&v[0], sizeof(v[0]), nmemb, stdout) != nmemb) {
    cerr << "failed to write the array\n";
    return 1;
  }
}
```

The drawback is that it is not portable: `sizeof(int)` and/or endianess, alignment can be different on different OSes.

#### Example

Convert to binary format integers stored in `array.txt`:

```
$ g++ convert-to-bin.cc -o convert-to-bin && 
  < array.txt ./convert-to-bin >array.bin
```

After that you can read integers efficiently from `array.bin`:

```
 $ g++ read-integer-array.cc -o read-integer-array &&
   < array.bin ./read-integer-array
```

The above assumes that you need to read integers from a file many times.